# Unable to connect to database using postman I get this error "message": "1146 is not a valid HTTP return status code", . I have reinstalled Xamp

Tags: php, xampp, postman

// Got this error
"title": "CodeIgniter\HTTP\Exceptions\HTTPException",
"type": "CodeIgniter\HTTP\Exceptions\HTTPException",
"code": 500,
"message": "1146 is not a valid HTTP return status code"

Comment: Please post the code that you're using that produces this error

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a database with a HTTP client?

Comment: Please add a sample code that is causing this. Also add relevant tags like codeigniter so that it would be search friendly.